# Cannot include opencv3 on OS X

Tags: c++, c, opencv, gcc, include

I am writing a really small project in C++ on OS X El cap with opencv3 installed from Homebrew through `brew install opencv3`, I tried what the official examples did and included this line on top of my file

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

It returned error saying

```
fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Tried with double quotes instead of <>, didn't work either, tried other modules like

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
```

With or without module path (highgui/), or <>, it's always file not found error

This is part of my Makefile:

```
CC=clang++
CFLAGS= -Wall -g -std=c++0x
LFLAGS=

CFILES=blahblah.cpp
HFILES=blahblah.hpp
OFILES=blahblah.o

all:    main

%.o:    %.cpp $(HFILES)                                                                                   
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LFLAGS)

main:   $(OFILES) $(HFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OFILES) -o main $(LFLAGS)
```

I included the include directory in the search path in the makefile, and got this error:

```
clang++ -Wall -g -std=c++0x main.o datatools.o extract.o -o main -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/include -I/usr/local/include
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::String::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::String::~String() in main.o
      cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

By the way, opencv2 works fine, and I didn't need to do anything about it, how should I get opencv3 library working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify header directory (`/usr/local/Cellar/your_opencv_header_dir`) into `Header search paths` in project's Build Settings.

You may also need to do the same for libraries or include them into the project.

Comment: Thank you, but I got into a new error, please see the edits.

Comment: `symbol not found` means you did not link libraries. Easiest way is to drag all the `opencv` libraries into to project and choose _create references_ on the pop-up window.

Comment: What do you mean by pop up window? Do you mean symlinks?

Comment: Forget what I said, just do what you need to do to link libraries in Xcode.

Comment: Oh, I saw `brew` and thought of Xcode. Then link all opencv libraries in `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib` in your makefile

Comment: That still gives me the same architecture error, and I can't link lopencv_core either, it says not found

Comment: check `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0/lib` if you see it.

Comment: Is that for a -L flag?